# Why is recaptcha not causing this test to fail?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, recaptcha

I am using Rails 3.1.0 and the recaptcha gem from [here](https://github.com/ambethia/recaptcha/).  I was running a cucumber test that checks that users can sign up.  Sign up requires users to fill out the captcha. I know that my test does not touch the captcha:

```
When /^I create a new account with email: "(.*?)" and password: "(.*?)"$/ do |email, pw|
    click_link "Sign up"
    fill_in "Email", :with => email
    fill_in "Password", :with => pw
    fill_in "Password confirmation", :with => pw
    click_button "Sign up"
end
```

But the test still passes. I check success by verifying that the successful sign up message is present on the page and the recaptcha failure message is not present using this step:

```
Then /^I should (not )?see "(.*)"$/ do |negate, text|
  if negate
    page.should_not have_content text
  else
    page.should have_content text
  end
end
```

The controller is almost identical to the first one suggested [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Use-Recaptcha-with-Devise).

```
  class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
    def create
      if verify_recaptcha
        super
      else
        build_resource
        clean_up_passwords(resource)
        flash.now[:alert] = "There was an error with the recaptcha code below. Please re-enter the code."      
        flash.delete :recaptcha_error
        render :new
      end
    end
  end
```

Is there any reason why recaptcha would not work in the test environment?  It seems to work fine in development.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Recaptcha by default does not verify the captcha in the test and cucumber environments (see [verify logic](https://github.com/ambethia/recaptcha/blob/master/lib/recaptcha/verify.rb#L12), [configuration logic](https://github.com/ambethia/recaptcha/blob/master/lib/recaptcha/configuration.rb#L44), and [default value](https://github.com/ambethia/recaptcha/blob/master/lib/recaptcha.rb#L11) ). If it weren't for this, either testing would be very difficult or the captcha wouldn't be very useful.

Comment: I thought that this might be the case but didn't see it mentioned anywhere on the github page. Didn't look at the source.

Answer (score 4):

Just to add to Bens answer and give a potential workaround:

To make sure things don't work (it "fails with recaptcha") in RSpec I've done

```
before do
  Recaptcha.configuration.skip_verify_env.delete('test')
end

after do
  Recaptcha.configuration.skip_verify_env << 'test'
end
```

Thanks Ben